# What exactly a constructor does and why this code is not working in constructor?

Tags: java, swing, constructor

I read about the constructer that a constructor is something that is used to set up the components of the container. So i wrote the following program which works well but only problem is that the label is not at the specified location i.e. 125,300. When I wrote the line label.setLocation(125,300) in the public run() then the code works well. Why it is not working when I write the line in the constructor? Basically it should work as the constructor is used to set up the components of the JFrame.

If not then What exactly is a constructor?

The Code:

```
public class RealGame extends JFrame implements Runnable, KeyListener{

JLabel label = new JLabel("I am a JLabel");
RealGame(){
    setVisible(true);
    requestFocus();
    setContentPane(new JPanel());
    getContentPane().setSize(640, 480);
    setSize(640, 480);
    label.setSize(50,50);
    label.setOpaque(true);
    label.setVisible(true);
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));        
    getContentPane().add(label);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new RealGame());
}


@Override
public void run() {
    label.setLocation(125,300); //THIS IS IMPORTANT
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello");
    System.out.println("Done");
    System.exit(0);
}


@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}


@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

}


@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

}
```

And also is the structure of the program correct? i.e. in many programs I saw that people use

```
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

   public run(){

   }

 });
```

But instead I instantiated the main class. Will it give any problems in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but only problem is that the label is not at the specified location i.e. 125,300.

What is special about (125, 300). Don't use magic numbers in your program.

Swing uses layout managers to position components in a panel. The layout manager will determine the size and location of your component.

Read the section from the Swingtutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples.

> in many programs I saw that people use

Yes all GUI components should be updated on the `Event Dispatch Thread(EDT)`. All the tutorial examples show you how to do this. You can also read the section in the tutorial on `Concurrency in Swing` for reasons why this is important.

> When I wrote the line label.setLocation(125,300) in the public run() then the code works well

The code is added to the end of the `EDT`, which means it executes AFTER the layout manager. However this is only temporary. Try resizing the frame and the label will go back to the position determined by the layout manager. Don't try to set the location manually!